# É necessário o ID por 'params.id' na rota sendo que já tenho o ID no 'auth.user.id'? AdonisJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonisjs

Estou com a seguinte dúvida ao criar as rotas e Controller do meu usuário.

Vejo que quando crio a rota com Route.resource automaticamente o Adonis cria as rotas de CRUD e passando por parâmetro o ID nas operações de Update/Show/Delete, porém não preciso deste ID na rota, uma vez que pego o ID pelo auth.user.id.

Como está minha criação da rota:

```
Route.group(() => {
  Route.resource("users", "UserController")
    .apiOnly()
    .except("store")
    .validator(new Map([[["users.update"], ["User/Update"]]]));
}).middleware(["auth"]);
```

Após a criação das rotas rodando o Adonis route:list consta que as rotas de Show, Update, Destroy precisam de id nas rotas.

A que ponto isso é necessário?
Se não, for como faço para não precisar passar o ID por parâmetro na rota?

A princípio é isso. Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após estudos foi entendido que uma vez que já temos o acesso ao ID do usuário por meio do middleware de autenticação, não precisamos passar por params na rota.

Porém como o método resource() de criação de rotas é automático, não conseguimos setar para que não haja parâmetros nas rotas.

Conclui que para não precisar passar o ID nas rotas precisamos criar as rotas manualmente dentro da

```js
Route.group()
```

Ficando desta forma:

```
Route.group(() => {
  //Update de usuário
  Route.put("users", "UserController").validator(
    new Map([[["users.update"], ["User/Update"]]])
  );

  //CRUD de documentos
  Route.resource("documents", "DocumentController").apiOnly();

  //CRUD de assinaturas
  Route.resource("signatures", "SignatureController").apiOnly();

  //Update Config
  Route.put("configurations", "ConfigurationController").validator(
    new Map([[["configurations.update"], ["UserConfig/Update"]]])
  );
}).middleware(["auth"]);
```